# What's the proper way to upload images?

Tags: support, uploading-images

I know how to add an image to an answer, and how to upload it. But sometimes I want to link to an image in a **comment**, and I'm not sure how to upload images then.
Here's what I do now: I start editing an answer, upload the image, so that the link to it is added to the text I'm editing, copy that link, cancel the edit and start writing a comment where I can paste the link. That works, but is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the technique you've been using, and of course if the image already exists on the 'Net somewhere you can simply paste a link to that in your comment... But as bemace notes in his answer here, Answers are far more valuable than comments - so if you can edit an existing one or post a new one, this stands to improve the site far more than simply tacking on a comment somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you shouldn't really need to. [Editing isn't just for typos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15839/editing-versus-answering/15843#15843). If the image helps illustrate the answer, go ahead and edit it into the answer. If you would have to significantly rewrite the answer to make the image fit you should probably just post your own answer.

It gets a little trickier with questions, but if you think you've got a good read on what they're trying to ask and have an image that would help others understand the question then I still lean toward "go for it". If you're worried you can leave a comment telling them they can roll it back if you've misinterpreted their question.

If you're not as sure you've understood them, you can post an answer like "If I've understood correctly that you're asking ... then you need to do ..." with your image. If it turns out you misunderstood you can delete or edit your answer.

If you're really not sure, then what you're doing is the best option available right now. You could try a feature request on the main meta for simplifying the process, just make sure it's clear you're not asking for the images to be *displayed* in the comments.

Comment: The occasion was a comment to a comment to a question, so it probably strayed away from the question, so that it might confuse readers ("what's this doing here?")